# How do I read out the value of my checkbox?

Tags: lightning, controller, slds, inputcheckboxes

I can't figure out how to read out the value from a checkbox. See my code below. Is there someone who can give me some tips?

[image: See my code]

Comment: where is the code, please share

Comment: where do you want to read the value? in the controller?

Comment: Yes, I want to read it in the controller.

Comment: Please don't use images for your code. Simply copy-pasting text is preferable.

Comment: Is this a lightning component? With just an input tag you need to get the element by Id and then the value. If you can use apex or lightning input component it would be easier

Comment: Yes this is in a lighting component and I could use a lightning input. How would that work?

Comment: @Eric any tip would help me :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this: :)

```
var selected = event.target.checked; //true or false
```

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_conditional

Answer (score 2):

To get the value, just get the value from the attribute you assigned:

```
var something = component.get("v.something__c");
```

Comment: This gives a value: undefined. There is also no change if it is checked or unchecked

Comment: @Ant We'll need to see more code. Preferably enough to reproduce the issue. I can say that, generically speaking, this should work. I've done it enough times to know that this is how it should work.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, more code is not a problem. 

The actual code in the component is this:  

<aura:attribute name="identityRequest"    type="Identity_Request__c"   description="Identity request record"/>

<div class="slds-form-element__row">
<div class="slds-form-element">
<label class="slds-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" aura:id="news" class="slds-input" value="{!v.identityRequest.Newsletter__c}" onchange="{!c.onChange}" />
<span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
</label>
</div>
</div>

And the code in the controller: see next comment

Comment: onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
  var identityRequest  = component.get('v.identityRequest');
  component.set('v.identityRequest',identityRequest);
  console.log('identityRequest..Newsletter__c); } 

As you can see Im pretty new to this, is this readable?

Comment: Btw I can read out: 

<lightning:input type="email" aura:id="email" value="{!v.identityRequest.Email__c}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input--bare slds-has-divider--bottom"  name="email" label="{!v.labels.email__c+' *'}" onchange="{!c.onChange}"/>

In the controller using the same controller code. So Im guessing im missing a step because its a checkbox

Comment: @Ant Oh, I think it should actually be "checked" instead of "value". Can you try that?

Comment: this doesn't work, by doing this it is not possible to check or uncheck the checkbox. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use something as :

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" label="Select?" change="{!c.onCheck}"/>
```

in component and

```
onCheck: function(cmp, evt) {
     var checkCmp = cmp.find("checkbox");
     resultCmp = cmp.find("checkResult");
     resultCmp.set("v.value", ""+checkCmp.get("v.value"));

 }
```

in controller. This should return the value is checked or not?

Answer (score 0):

In case when normal html input tag is used, event.target.checked will return if the checkbox has just been checked or not. event.target.value will return the value